# Difference between Propositional and Judgmental Equality

Tags: logic, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

I'm reading the  [HoTT](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/)  book and actually I'm a bit confused on core difference between
propositional equality (noation: $a=_A b$ where $a, b:A$ and judgmental equality
$ a \equiv b $.

The propositional equality is just a proposition and therefore a type $a=_A b$ and
checking if $a=_A b$ is true is equivalent to find a term $t: a=_A b$.

In contrast $ a \equiv b $ is a judgement, so statement about the theory and
not in. In the book one involved reason why we need also the judgmental equality
is to be able to make reasonable definitions like declaring a function
$f: A \to B$ to be $x^2$: $f(x) \equiv x^2$.

Intuitively this differs from propositional equality because it's a definition
we did and the theory not 'knows it'. So it seems senseless to try to prove
in the theory if $f(x) = x^2$, because *we* defined it so while the theory
we want to talk about is *stiff*, informally speaking 'we cannot define something
within the theory'.

At least, that's how I understood the difference between propositional equality
and judgmental equality. First of all, is this 'intuition' correct or
'misleading' and(or) wrong? The reason why I think that it might be shortcoming is the remark
on page 19 that 'As type theory becomes more complicated, judgmental equality
can get more subtle than this.' So I doubt that what I write above hits
to essential nature of the difference between propositional
and judgmental equality.

Question: Can the difference between propositional and judgmental equality made
be precise and does it coinside with my understandings of it sketched above
or did I miss the point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your intuition is correct, but is a simplified understanding of the difference between propositional and judgemental equality. That's exactly the meaning of the sentence in the HoTT book that you are quoting in chapter 1.1: this chapter is meant to be an introduction to help understand type theory, and does not pretend to be exact and exhaustive in the details.

When you try to formalize a (informal) theory, you end up with a syntaxical representation of the objects of the theory, and syntaxic rules to manipulate these objects. With a simple theory, each object has a unique syntaxical representation: then there is no need of definitional (or judgmental) equality.

But most of the time, it is impossible to have a single syntaxical representation of each object; then you need to add additional rules, the [conversion rules](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/language/core/conversion.html), that specify when 2 different syntaxical expressions represent the same object in the theory. 2 syntaxical expressions are definitionaly equal when they are different representations of the *same* object in the theory.

For instance, you usually want to ignore the differences in the naming of the variables: you need an $\alpha$-conversion rule to specify that two expressions differing only by the names encode the same object of theory.

Then you have the computation rules, that identify the syntaxical representation $f(a)$ with the result of the computation of $f$ applied to $a$ ($\beta$-conversion). You also want to identify an expression using notations with the expression obtained by replacing the notation by its definition.

The exact border between definitional and propositional equality is not always easy to draw (e.g. this [note](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/language/core/conversion.html#expansion)). It may be desirable, e.g. to simplify the formal proofs, that two objects that are proved to be propositionally equal are made definitionally equal with a new specific conversion rule. This can possibly be done with an [equality reflection rule](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extensional+type+theory); however, such a rule has an impact on the meta-theoretical properties of the theory, such as the decidability of type checking.

It is desirable that, in the formalization of a theory, objects have a unique syntaxical representation, or, at least, can be converted into a unique syntaxical representation (strong normalization property). For a theory dealing with simple objects, propositional equality is then trivial and reduces to definitional equality. But for a theory dealing with more complex objects such as spaces or structures, admitting possibly different equivalent definitions *inside* the theory, the desired notion of equality of objects (space or structure) should be an equivalence of objects (space or structure), and therefore cannot be reduced to the definitional equality. Homotopy type theory and its univalence axiom is meant to achieve such a goal.

Comment: probably a banal question, but if you say 'object' of a type theory what do you mean precisely? A type, a term or can be meant in your answer both as well?

Comment: Let me try to summarize it: so a judgemental equality
is an equality between two 'objects' (as far as I understand
you here an 'object' can be a type OR a term of
a type) which is derivible by given 'rules', while
a propositional equality is a type which contains
an inhabitant: that is we have 'somehow' to construct 
it, but how is in general a 'big problem', in the
sense that it is NOT derivable with given 'rules'. 
That's how I understood (or possibly misunderstood) 
your answer. Does the approach to summarize it make
sense?

Comment: @IsaktheXI I was using the word 'object' to mean the things that you want to formalize in a type theory; at the end, they consitute a model of the type theory. An object can be modelized as, or is a model of, either a term or a type.
The inhabitants of a type are also constructed with rules, but not of the same sort as the rules for judgmental equality: they correspond to different sort of judgements (see HoTT book beginning of chapter A.2). For the rest you are correct: with the strong normalization property, judgemental equality is decidable, while propositionnal equality is not in general.

Comment: Now I'm confused a bit. As far as I undersand it
the judgements in general (especially our
judgmental equality) are derived by the rules
of inference. These guys are exactly introduced in Ch. A.2 (as far as I understand you correctly)
Now you remarked that inhabitants of a type are also
constructed with rules, but not of the same sort as the 
rules for judgmental equality.

Comment: What is the difference between rules we use to derive
judgements and rules to construct inhabitants of a 
certain type?

Comment: I think I understand your point how! When you are were talking about
rules that 'tells how to construct inhabitants of certain types' you refer to rules like eg the introduction rule (p 424), which essentially
says that if we have as assumption several inhabitants
of certain types given, then it tells us that the
constructed object in an inhabitant of the new type
(and implicitely it indeed guides how to construct it), right?

Comment: I think I found also the reason for my confusion. I learned 
that rules are some kind of 'wires' how it is allowed
in our deductive system to derive judgement $J$ from
judgements $J_1,...J_n$. And formally the introduction rule
is the same: we start with serveral judgement of the form
$a_i$ has type $A$ and the rule says  that 
$a(a_1,...,a_n)$ has type $A$. So formally it has also the
shape 'judgements imply new judgement' but it gives 
additionaly a way to construct canonically a new 
inhabitant of type $A$. Was that the point you intended to 
stress in last comment?

Comment: Yes. A judgment of the sort $\Gamma\vdash a:A$ usually introduces a new term $a$ inhabiting an already introduced type $A$ (sometimes both $a$ and $A$ are already introduced, and the judgment just specifies that $a$ inhabits $A$).
A judgment of the sort $\Gamma\vdash a\equiv a' : A$ usually introduces a judgmental equality between the terms $a$ and $a'$ that are already introduced, and known to inhabit the type $A$.